# anchor tag inside a button that controls the collapse of another div not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, bootstrap-5

On my Nuxt 2 SSR + Bootstrap 5 app I have the following code:

```
    <button 
        v-for="file of orderProduct.files"
        class="collapsed son-collapse" 
        type="button" 
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        :data-bs-target="`#collapseField${orderProduct.id}`"
        aria-expanded="false"
        :aria-controls="`collapseField${orderProduct.id}`"
    >
                            
        <p><i class="fa fa-file-alt"></i> {{ file.original_filename }}</p>
        <div>
            <a 
                @click.stop
                :href="`http://example.com`"
                target="_blank"
            >
                <i class="far fa-eye"></i>Ver
            </a>
            <span>{{ file.page_count }} {{ $tc('home.pagina', file.page_count) }}</span>
        </div>
    </button>
    <div 
        :id="`collapseField${orderProduct.id}`"
        class="collapse summary cost-ajax" 
    >  
       ...
    </div>
```

When the user clicks on the button, Bootstap's JS Collapse component toggles the corresponding div. And that is OK. However, I want a tab to open when a user clicks on the anchor tag.

Well, that is not happening. Not only is the tab not opening, but the div is being toggled, because the click event on the anchor propagates into the button.
I thought that it could all be a problem with event bubbling, so I used the Vue.js built-in event modifier @click.stop. I also tried calling a method and there calling e.stopPropagation(). Nothing of this has affected the behavior of the app at all.

Finally, I find it curious that, when clicking on the i tag inside the anchor, the tab does open. The collapsable element keeps toggling though.

Comment: try changing the `a` into a `div` and use `@click.prevent="something"` and create a function that does what you want

Comment: If I change the layout the designer gets angry

Comment: it won't change the layout or the design, you can style a div to act and visually look like the `a` tag, so the designer won't see a difference

Answer (score 0):

You're facing an issue because the `<button>` element contains the `<a>` element, and hence the click on the anchor tag is propagating to the button and triggering the Bootstrap collapse. Using `@click.stop` in Vue is the right approach to stop event propagation, but seems like it isn't working in this scenario.

So you have to use JavaScript's native `event.stopPropagation()` method within a method handler to stop the propagation:

```
<a 
    @click="stopPropagation"
>
    <i class="far fa-eye"></i>Ver
</a>
```

and in your methods:

```
methods: {
    stopPropagation(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        window.open(event.currentTarget.href, '_blank');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried both approaches, but the behaviour keeps the same. I think that it all could be something about Bootstarp's javascript that escapes me.

Comment: It works halfway. The tab now opens, but the event keeps propagating to the button and thus toggling the div.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having both the button and anchor tag inside the same container, separate them. You can place the anchor tag outside of the button so that clicking the anchor won't affect the button's behavior.

```
<button
  v-for="file of orderProduct.files"
  class="collapsed son-collapse"
  type="button"
  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
  :data-bs-target="`#collapseField${orderProduct.id}`"
  aria-expanded="false"
  :aria-controls="`collapseField${orderProduct.id}`"
>
  <p><i class="fa fa-file-alt"></i> {{ file.original_filename }}</p>
  <div>
    {{ file.page_count }} {{ $tc('home.pagina', file.page_count) }}
  </div>
</button>
<a
  @click.stop
  :href="`http://example.com`"
  target="_blank"
>
  <i class="far fa-eye"></i>Ver
</a>
```

and you can Separate Click Handlers:
By separating the button and anchor, you can handle the click events differently for each element. You should attach the data-bs-toggle attributes only to the button element, so it controls the collapsing behavior. The anchor tag can have its own click handler to open a new tab.

```
<button
  v-for="file of orderProduct.files"
  class="collapsed son-collapse"
  type="button"
  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
  :data-bs-target="`#collapseField${orderProduct.id}`"
  aria-expanded="false"
  :aria-controls="`collapseField${orderProduct.id}`"
>
  <p><i class="fa fa-file-alt"></i> {{ file.original_filename }}</p>
  <div>
    {{ file.page_count }} {{ $tc('home.pagina', file.page_count) }}
  </div>
</button>
<a
  @click.prevent
  :href="`http://example.com`"
  target="_blank"
>
  <i class="far fa-eye"></i>Ver
</a>
```

Note the use of @click.prevent on the anchor tag to prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag and open the link in a new tab without affecting the button's collapse behavior.